# Writing one record at a time, use one static class?

Tags: c#, .net, class

I am writing one line of text in a file every time a button is pressed.

I have defined a static class like this:

```
public static class PalletRecord
{
    public static string MachineName { get; set; }
    public static DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public static string BranchPlant { get; set; }
    public static string Location { get; set; }
    public static string Data { get; set; }
    public static string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public static string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public static decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Every time i need to write to a file i populate the static class properties and i use File.AppendAllLines to write to text file.

Should i have done it with a non-static class?

Comment: there's probably not really a 'right' answer here. *I* would probably have used an instance of the class, but if your method using static properies works, then who's to say it's wrong?

Comment: Cana you show how you are creating the instance of the class can you show the Button_Click event code..? also is this a Console application or a winforms application..?

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely write it with an immutable class that requires those parameters in its constructor.

Comment: you class is not staic your variables are

Comment: sorry it is static indeed, i corrected my post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes ! Using statics to keep state like this is going to get you in trouble. This might especially be true if you might need multi threading now or in the future, since the static state is shared by all threads. Another problem could be an incomplete initialization bug, leaving you with ½ the state from a previous record and ½ the state from a new record.

A much better approach would be to make the properties non-static, and create one instance of the class with the correct properties for each record. You could make a constructor which sets the properties, so that you know you have a valid record whenever you have an instance (also consider making the property setters private).

This also better models the problem you are working with. You write multiple, different records in the file, this is best represented by instances of a class that represents a record. In my opinion, using an instance of your class for  each record you need to write is the proper clean object oriented way to do this.

Comment: Another issue is if you don't remember to re-initialize all the values back to default states (especially if you do not set values each time) will use the last-used values from the previous write.

Comment: Yeah, I can think of other problems too, but incomplete initialization is also very likely to occur; added that to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference. If it works it works. Creating a new class uses more memory. I would create a new class, but not a big deal anyway. If it saving in database and discarded, your solution works. If the records are saved in memory, I would create a new class for each record.

Comment: Works... until more than one thread tries to use it at once, or you don't fully "clean/reinitialize" the values from its previous usage.

Comment: I highly doubt that there are going to be serious memory problems as a result of creating a handful of instances of a type with a few dozen bytes in it.  They have such a short lifetime that it won't ever add up to anything worth thinking about.